# How do I downgrade from Yarn2 to Yarn1?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

I'm using macOS and after installing Yarn2 several important tools no longer function. I've logged issues with them but in the meantime I need to get back to Yarn Classic. `brew uninstall yarn` and then tried `brew install yarn@1.22.5` but this failed with an unknown version error message.

Comment: Running `yarn set version classic` appears to have no effect.

`~/Sites/supporters-united(redwood2)» yarn set version classic                                                 ➤ YN0000: Downloading https://nightly.yarnpkg.com/latest.js
➤ YN0000: Saving the new release in .yarn/releases/yarn-1.23.0-20200827.1658.cjs
➤ YN0000: Done in 0.54s
~/Sites/supporters-united(redwood2)» yarn --version                                                           2.2.2`

Answer (score 7):

Trick is to check for a `~/.yarnrc.yml` file and if present remove any line for the `yarnPath` variable.

Comment: Or, in my case, the trick is to ensure that **when you run `yarn set version 1.22.19`, do so in your home directory**. Yarn seems to be a little "dumb" in this regard - it will create the necessary files in whatever your current working directory is (even though it needs to be done in your home directory).

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete all yarn related files in my home directory (windows) which was generated when I upgraded to yarn3 before running `yarn set version 1.22.19`